# Is a visa required to tour Amsterdam via KLM flight?

Tags: visas

We are travelling to USA by KLM flight and have a halt at Amsterdam. If we wish to tour Amsterdam for 3-4 days, will we be requiring a Schengen Visa?

Comment: You should probably tell us your nationality and country of origin

Comment: I'm not sure you'd be allowed to spend 3-4 days in Amsterdam's Schipol airport, even if for some reason you wanted to, so you'll need to enter the Netherlands (part of the Schengen area) no matter what

Answer (score 6):

If you want to (or have to) leave the transit lounge of the airport, you do need to be allowed to enter the Schengen area according to the usual rules. There are no exception for passengers in transit or short-term visas on-arrival like there is in some other countries. Depending on your situation and in particular on your citizenship, it might indeed mean that you need a visa. US citizens do not.

Finally, if you are from a country whose citizens do need a Schengen visa, being a US resident or having a US visa does not help (it does exempt you from any visa requirement for [*airport* transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) but not for a short visit to the city while in transit).